# Does the strength of a smell depend on the volume or surface area of an agglomerate of material?

Tags: perception

I just switched from Timberland to Adidas shoes, and noticed a horrible trait of the [Adidas tread](http://www.tactics.com/a/3s5h/9/adidas-campus-vulc-skate-shoes-black-turquoise-white-sole.jpg): instead of being composed of externally-protruding bumps like the Timberland, it is composed of channels striated *internally*. This has the horrible trait of trapping and making difficult to remove small pebbles, mud, and other foreign objects that one might inadvertently step on.

Assuming that one were to step on an unusually aromatic organic viscoplastic, **would the 'strength' of the smell depend on the surface area of the exposed agglomerate, or of its mass**? My instinct leads me to think that the surface area would be the major factor, but empirically I see that larger massed agglomerates, even if wedged deep within an Adidas tread with little exposed surface area, seem to be more easily detected by human olfactory organs. However I contend that my sensing apparatus and testng methodology are not scientifically sound, nor do I have access to facilities which would allow me to make more objective observations.

Of course, the principle of "a month in the lab could save an hour in the library" applies, so I searched online but found surprisingly little (read: none) literature on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exposed surface area usually wins out over mass as far as emitting smells, unless you're talking about extremely thin films that "deplete" quickly. As for why you're observing a stronger mass dependence, I suspect there's enough experimental variability that it's hard to get a good measurement.

However, with the internal channels you get an additional trait absent with the Timberland tread: the ability for material wedged deep inside the channels to stay moist and fester. This  may exacerbate the smell.

What  manner of material is usually wedged in the shoe?

Comment: The **S**melly **H**ighly **I**nhospitable **T**errible manner of material is usually wedged in the shoe.